# Makefile shell usage and looping over file array

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

My knowledge about makefiles is very rusty. As part of a build phase I want to:

- Loop over all files in a directory "javalibs"
- For each .jar file, call "jar xf jarfile" to extract all classes from that jar file. Since jar xf only allows to extract to the current location, I must cd to a certain directory

So that's my final goal, having all classes in some certain directory (rationale behind this is that later I run ProGuard from over these classes).

My problem is that... well... my makefile knowledge sucks =). This is the part where I want to loop over these files:

```
$(classes): $(all-javas) $(all-properties) $(alljars)
    @rm -rf $(stage1)
    @mkdir -p $(stage1)
#   cur_dir=$(shell basename $(CURDIR))
    jars=`find $(makefile_dir)/$(javalibs) -name *.jar`
#$(wildcard $(javalibs)/*.jar)
    for jar in $(jars) ; do  \
        (wd=$$(pwd); \
        cd "$$makefile_dir/$$stage1" ; \
        `jar xf "$$makefile_dir/$$jar"` ; \
        echo "jar xf $$makefile_dir/$$jar" ;) \
    done
#   cd $(cur_dir)
    $(javac) -d $(stage1) -sourcepath $(src) \
        -bootclasspath $(vm-build)/classpath $(javas)
    cp $(all-properties) $(stage1)/
```

My expected result would be that the call

```
jar xf "$$makefile_dir/$$jar"
```

Would actually be called on the shell. Instead, I just get an echo of this for loop when executing the makefile:

```
for jar in  ; do  \
        (wd=$(pwd); \
        cd "$makefile_dir/$stage1" ; \
        `jar xf "$makefile_dir/$jar"` ; \
        echo "jar xf $makefile_dir/$jar" ;) \
    done
```

Notice the missing array above: "for jar in  ".

My expected result would be that there is an array in "jars", which is looped over. But probably I cannot initialize an array in such way?

What I'm asking for is some kind assistance to help me understand how to initialize an array from the return value of the shell. And whether my syntax above is correct otherwise.

Update:
I never got the suggested answer working (but this may be because of me). But instead I made this:

```
define stageLibraryJar 
    (cd $(libraries) && jar xf $(1))
    echo Extrcated $(1) to libraries
    cd $(makefile_dir)

endef

.PHONY: build
build: prepare-libraries make-vm $(xcode-build)/$(release)/hello.app/hello

.PHONY: prepare-libraries
prepare-libraries: 
    rm -rf $(libraries).classes
    mkdir -p $(libraries).classes
    @rm -rf  $(libraries)
    @mkdir -p  $(libraries)
    @rm -rf $(stage1)
    @mkdir -p $(stage1)
    $(foreach jar,$(library-jars), $(call stageLibraryJar,$(makefile_dir)/$(jar)))
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it. But it works

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do it with a shell loop inside the command, but this way is much easier:

```
JARS := $(shell find $(makefile_dir)/$(javalibs) -name "*.jar")

$(info jar files are $(JARS))
# be sure this looks right before you proceed

MODULES := $(patsubst %.jar,%.module,$(JARS))  # "module" is just a name

all: $(MODULES)

.PHONY: $(MODULES)
$(MODULES): %.module :
    @cd $(makefile_dir)/$(stage1) ; jar xf $(makefile_dir)/$*.jar
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks much cleaner indeed. However, no matter what I try, my MODULES is always empty. Hm. Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I never got this to work, but maybe it is just because of me.

Comment: @benjist: What was in `JARS`?

Comment: I've just renamed JARS into library-jars. It contains a list of paths relative the makefile dir (previously I also used the absoulte path for your code). Now defined as: library-jars = $(shell find $(javalibs) -name '*.jar')

Comment: @benjist: And *what was in it?* Can you give one or two examples of these paths?

Comment: javalibs/jetty-all-9.2.1.v20140609.jar
 javalibs/servlet-api-3.1.0.jar

Comment: @benjist: And `MODULES` was empty, using the makefile above? That's very strange.

Comment: Yes. But my makefile is a bit more complex and I had to change it a little bit. Meaning, maybe it was my fault that it didn't work. I'll maybe try again. But since all works for now, I'll stick with what I have. But you led my to a direction, so I upvote.

Comment: I'll accept this answer then when I've got your proposed solution working.